# ¿Qué quiere decir "badulaque"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, república-dominicana

Leo en [La fiesta del Chivo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_fiesta_del_Chivo_(novela)) (2000), de Mario Vargas Llosa, este fragmento. Situémonos en República Dominicana, años 1960.

> Balaguer lo decía en sus memorias: Trujillo se puso blanco, vibró de indignación. Ordenó que se cancelara el desfile militar y la juramentación de Ramfis como jefe del Estado Mayor Conjunto. Y, antes de partir, cogió una copa e hizo un brindis qu equería ser una bofetada simbólica al **badulaque** (la borrachera le impediría enterarse): «Brindo por el trabajo, lo único que traerá prosperidad a la República».

Para dar contexto, creo bueno explicar que se trata de un momento en el que se narra cómo el dictador de República Dominicana, Leónidcas Trujillo, actuó ante el comportamiento de su hijo Ramfis cuando este volvía de Estados Unidos. Había ido para cursar una titulación del ejército, pero fue expulsado. Para maquillar el fracaso, su padre decidió recibirlo con toda la plana mayor del ejército y condecorarlo. Sin embargo, cuando Ramfis salió del avión se vio que borracho y se acabó suspendiendo el acto.

Todo esto para traer a colación la palabra *badulaque*. Resulta que en España la usamos coloquialmente para nombrar a esas tiendas que abren muchas horas, venden comida y normalmente regentadas por inmigrantes asiáticos (paquistaníes en concreto). Sin embargo, en este contexto veo que Vargas Llosa lo utiliza con sentido despectivo, algo así como sinónimo de *holgazán*, que no encuentro en el DAMER. Allí se lee:

> [**badulaque**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=badulaque).
>
> I.    1.  sust/adj. Pe, Bo. Persona que está ociosa voluntariamente. pop + cult → espon ^ desp.
>
> II.   1.  m. pl. Ho; Ve, desp. Enseres personales de escaso valor.
>   2.  m. Ho. p.u. Cosa inservible o de escaso valor.
>
> III.  1.  m-f. Ch, Py. Persona de conducta bellaca, canalla.
>   2.  adj/sust. Py. Referido a persona, pícara, sinvergüenza. pop + cult → espon.
>
> IV.   1.  sust/adj. Ec. p.u. Persona que cumple tardíamente o no cumple nunca lo que promete. pop + cult → espon ^ desp.

Tal vez la entrada III podría encajar, pero veo que en ningún caso se relaciona con República Dominicana.

Así pues, ¿qué uso tiene *badulaque* en República Dominicana? ¿Cuál es su origen?

Comment: De hecho yo creo que _badulaque_ se puso de moda a partir de Los Simpsons por el nombre de la tienda de Apu, pero semejante definición (como tienda) no aparece en [la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4llJVEa), donde se define como "persona necia, inconsistente", además de otra definición similar a la del DAMER para Ecuador.

Comment: No basta [esto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4llJVEa)?

Comment: @Rafael efectivamente, sí. Pensé que debía tener algún significado regional especial, por lo que no acudí al DLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque el texto esté ambientado en la República Dominicana de la década de los 60, fue escrito en el año 2000 por un peruano que por entonces llevaba como unos treinta años viviendo en España. Así que veo más lógico darle a la palabra el sentido que aplica en España:

> **[badulaque](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4llJVEa)**
>
> 3. m. y f. Persona necia, inconsistente. U. t. c. adj.

Para darle más profundidad a esta definición, indicar que la palabra viene ya recogida en el diccionario de Covarrubias de 1611 (como "badvlaqve"), aunque la definición del *Diccionario de Autoridades* (1726) es mucho más esclarecedora (negritas mías):

> BADULAQUE. s.m. Guisado de carne menúda, dividida y cortada en pedazos pequeños, y con el caldo espesso, el qual se compone de livianos y bofes, como lo que comunmente se llama chanfaina.
>   BADULAQUE. Metaphoricamente, y por alusión al guisado, que es de poca substancia, se llama **el que es medio bobo, de poca ò ninguna actividad y maña, inutil, y de ningun provecho**.

Se encuentran casos de este uso metafórico del término desde el siglo XVII (año 1640 según Corominas).

En todo caso, buscando en el CORDE casos de *badulaque* y eliminando los casos de España, aún se encuentran muchos en el resto de países de habla hispana. Por ejemplo, el propio Vargas Llosa escribía antes de salir de su Perú natal:

> *—No sé qué pensar, flaco —se había puesto serio, Zavalita, había agravado la voz—. Pasas de un extremo a otro, es difícil entenderte. Mira, creo que preferiría que terminaras de comunista antes que de borrachín y de badulaque.*
>
> Mario Vargas Llosa, "Conversación en la catedral", 1969 (Perú).

Ningún caso concreto en la República Dominicana, pero sí en Cuba que está cerquita:

> *Hoy que en su contra con placer se afana
>
>   Hasta el pobre y mezquino badulaque,
>
>   Yo que indigno lo juzgo de un reproche
>
>   Le bendigo y le canto a troche y moche.*
>
> El Cucalambé (Juan Cristóbal Nápoles Fajardo), "Poesías completas", 1840-a1862 (Cuba).